# Excel: Convert time in format 0h20 to integer

Tags: excel, timestamp

I have the following timestamp exported from ERP software, for example: 0h20 or 2h30.

I want to convert this timestamp to an integer in Excel.

Does anybody know how to do this in Excel?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want the integer to represent seconds or minutes or hours??

Comment: Sorry for the incompleteness, but I would like to have it in minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the integer number of minutes, with data in **A1**, in another cell enter:

```
=60*LEFT(A1,FIND("h",A1)-1)+MID(A1,FIND("h",A1)+1,9999)
```

to get the integer number of seconds use:

```
=60*(60*LEFT(A1,FIND("h",A1)-1)+MID(A1,FIND("h",A1)+1,9999))
```

Comment: Excel reports an error in the formula, and it doesn't give any error information.

Comment: Make sure the cell includes that lower case **h** just as in your examples.

Comment: This one works:
`=60*LEFT(A1;FIND("h";A1)-1)+MID(A1;FIND("h";A1)+1;9999)`

Answer (score 0):

What should that integer be? The total minutes?

If so:

=SUMPRODUCT(0+MID("00000"&A1,FIND("h","00000"&A1)-{5,-1},5),{60,1})

which will work with values having an hour entry up to and including 9999, provided that there is always an "h" present in the string, i.e. 10 minutes is in the form 0h10, and not just 10.

Regards

Comment: Maybe it is my fault, but Excel reports an error in the formula.

Comment: I assume you changed the commas to semi-colons if that's what your system uses as argument separator?